# add two buttons with gridview

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to add two buttons in `relative` layout with `gridview`.

but i when i am adding second `button` its not working even crashing sometimes.

my desire design is

:-[image]

but its adding only one button successfully. so my one button code is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/delete_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Delete selected image" />



    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/delete_button"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
    </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and getting out put this:-

[image]

**How can i add my second button between grid and bottom button.**

Comment: What is the exception shown in the logcat ?
Is it a ClassCastException ? You might want to clean and rebuild your project?

Comment: can you post your xml code with second button added and logcat details of crash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/delete_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Delete selected image" />

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >

</GridView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/delete_button"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
    android:text="SecondButton" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Add your second button on top of the first button and to the right

```
android:layout_above="@+id/delete_button"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

hey try with this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/delete_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Delete selected image" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/add_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/delete_button"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="add Button" />

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/add_button"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
</GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the screen shot

[image].

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.Its working

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/delete_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Delete selected image" />



        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/save_button"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:columnWidth="90dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
        </GridView>
     <Button
            android:id="@+id/save_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_above="@+id/delete_button"
            android:text="Save" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your Gridview layout contains many elements that can then exceed the screen view, I advise you to provide a scrollView Layout:

So the source code is bellow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/border_blue_solid_transparent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/gridView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:columnWidth="90dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
                android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
            </GridView>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="Button" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```